# how do I create a svg sprite and then get the coordinates for each svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sprite

I can create a transparent image with several images using gimp and use http://www.spritecow.com/ to get the image coordinates for sprite.

what is the best way to create svg sprite ? I have several svgs - and I would like to create a single svg sprite image and then get the coordinate to create the individual classes.

I am on windows machines - so I am hoping for a online solution.

thanks

Comment: If they're unicolor, icon fonts is a pretty popular method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may I suggest that you look at icomoon.com/app. The service is very similar to your spritecow.

The better part is you take individual svg and upload it - and then download the sprite.